# Plot trees for a Random Forest in Python with Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, tree, scikit-learn, random-forest, pydot

I want to plot a decision tree of a random forest. So, i create the following code:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
import pydotplus
import six
from sklearn import tree
dotfile = six.StringIO()
i_tree = 0
for tree_in_forest in clf.estimators_:
if (i_tree <1):        
    tree.export_graphviz(tree_in_forest, out_file=dotfile)
    pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dotfile.getvalue()).write_png('dtree'+ str(i_tree) +'.png')
    i_tree = i_tree + 1
```

But it doesn't generate anything..
Have you an idea how to plot a decision tree from random forest?

Answer (score 44):

Assuming your Random Forest model is already fitted, 
first you should first import the `export_graphviz` function:

```
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
```

In your for cycle you could do the following to generate the `dot` file

```
export_graphviz(tree_in_forest,
                feature_names=X.columns,
                filled=True,
                rounded=True)
```

The next line generates a png file

```
os.system('dot -Tpng tree.dot -o tree.png')
```

Comment: I think there is no attribute of tree in random forest, isn't it?

Comment: @LKM, a Random Forest is a list of trees. You can get that list using the `estimators_` attribute. You can export for example the first tree using `random_forest.estimators_[0]`.

Comment: "export_graphviz" can be used only for decision trees but not Random Forests.

Comment: @LKM a tree is an element of the list `clf.estimators_`

Comment: len(random_forest.estimators_) gives the number of trees.

Answer (score 43):

After you fit a random forest model in scikit-learn, you can visualize individual decision trees from a random forest. The code below first fits a random forest model.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn import tree
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Load the Breast Cancer Dataset
data = load_breast_cancer()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)
df['target'] = data.target

# Arrange Data into Features Matrix and Target Vector
X = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'target']
y = df.loc[:, 'target'].values

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

# Random Forests in `scikit-learn` (with N = 100)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,
                            random_state=0)
rf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

You can now visualize individual trees. The code below visualizes the first decision tree.

```
fn=data.feature_names
cn=data.target_names
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1,ncols = 1,figsize = (4,4), dpi=800)
tree.plot_tree(rf.estimators_[0],
               feature_names = fn, 
               class_names=cn,
               filled = True);
fig.savefig('rf_individualtree.png')
```

The image below is what is saved.

[image]

Because this question asked for trees, you can visualize all the estimators (decision trees) from a random forest if you like. The code below visualizes the first 5 from the random forest model fit above.

```
# This may not the best way to view each estimator as it is small
fn=data.feature_names
cn=data.target_names
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1,ncols = 5,figsize = (10,2), dpi=900)
for index in range(0, 5):
    tree.plot_tree(rf.estimators_[index],
                   feature_names = fn, 
                   class_names=cn,
                   filled = True,
                   ax = axes[index]);

    axes[index].set_title('Estimator: ' + str(index), fontsize = 11)
fig.savefig('rf_5trees.png')
```

The image below is what is saved.

[image]

The code was adapted from this [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-decision-trees-with-python-scikit-learn-graphviz-matplotlib-1c50b4aa68dc).

Answer (score 5):

To access the single decision tree from the random forest in scikit-learn use `estimators_` attribute:

```py
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
# first decision tree
rf.estimators_[0]
```

Then you can use standard way to visualize the decision tree:

- you can print the tree representation, with sklearn `export_text`
- export to graphiviz and plot with sklearn `export_graphviz` method
- plot with matplotlib with sklearn `plot_tree` method
- use `dtreeviz` package for tree plotting

The code with example output are described in this [post](https://mljar.com/blog/visualize-decision-tree/).

The important thing to while plotting the single decision tree from the random forest is that it might be fully grown (default hyper-parameters). It means the tree can be really depth. For me, the tree with depth greater than 6 is very hard to read. So if the tree visualization will be needed I'm building random forest with `max_depth` < 7. You can check the example visualization in this [post](https://mljar.com/blog/visualize-tree-from-random-forest/).

Answer (score 1):

you can view each tree like this,

```
i_tree = 0
for tree_in_forest in FT_cls_gini.estimators_:
    if (i_tree ==3):        
        tree.export_graphviz(tree_in_forest, out_file=dotfile)
        graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dotfile.getvalue())        
    i_tree = i_tree + 1
Image(graph.create_png())
```

Comment: Can you add some more explanation regarding how this is different from the other answers? Works better than just dumping code

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a single tree:

```
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from IPython import display
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

m = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1, max_depth=3, bootstrap=False, n_jobs=-1)
m.fit(X_train, y_train)

str_tree = export_graphviz(m, 
   out_file=None, 
   feature_names=X_train.columns, # column names
   filled=True,        
   special_characters=True, 
   rotate=True, 
   precision=0.6)

display.display(str_tree)
```

Comment: Do you have idea what mean the parameters ratio and precision in the "draw_tree" function?

Comment: This method does not work anymore, because the `.structured` package has been removed from the library

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the solution given above, you can try this (hopefully for anyone that may need this in the future).

```
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from six import StringIO 

i_tree = 0
dot_data = StringIO()
for tree_in_forest in rfc.estimators_:#rfc random forest classifier
    if (i_tree ==3):        
        export_graphviz(tree_in_forest, out_file=dot_data)
        graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())        
    i_tree = i_tree + 1
Image(graph.create_png())
```