# Random Forest Classifier decision path visualisation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

```
# training forest
clf_random_Forest = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=8, 
min_samples_split=300)
clf_random_Forest.fit(training_data,training_label)
# method in use
clf_random_Forest.decision_path(test_data)
```

I read the documentation and found this method, but its description is not very informative, to put it mildly.
did anyone come across this method? can I visualize it, if so how?
Here I found only one question about this method, but in the answers I suggested visualizing individual trees.

Comment: You can checkout this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155128/plot-trees-for-a-random-forest-in-python-with-scikit-learn

Comment: i don't need trees visualization
i need decision_path()